# Why won't TypeScript allow referencing const variables in type definitions?

Tags: typescript

I can define a type restricting the input string to two possible values:

```
type STATE_TYPE = 'DRAFT'|'PUBLISHED'

function myFunc(state: STATE_TYPE) {
...
}
```

But I cannot define the two values as const and reference them in the type definition:

```
const DRAFT = 'DRAFT'
const PUBLISHED = 'PUBLISHED'

type STATE_TYPE = DRAFT|PUBLISHED  # <<---- not allowed
```

Comment: Because you can't use a value as a type: https://tsplay.dev/weLPaW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)

> TypeScript’s type system allows you to build new types out of existing
> ones using a large variety of operators.

In the first example 'DRAFT' and 'PUBLISHED' are both used as types and not values. They are called [String Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) after all.

To have the second example equivalent to the first you will have to get the type of DRAFT and PUBLISHED.

```
const DRAFT = 'DRAFT'
const PUBLISHED = 'PUBLISHED'

type STATE_TYPE = typeof DRAFT | typeof PUBLISHED
```